# extract multiple sub-fields from Pandas dataframe column into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe (approx 100k rows) as my input. It is an export from a database, and each of the fields in one of the columns contain one or more records which I need to expand into independent records. For example:

| record_id | text_field |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | r0_sub_record1_field1@r0_sub_record1_field2#r0_sub_record2_field1@r0_sub_record2_field2# |
| 1 | sub_record1_field1@sub_record1_field2# |
| 2 | sub_record1_field1@sub_record1_field2#sub_record2_field1@sub_record2_field2#sub_record3_field1@sub_record3_field2# |

The desired result should look like this:

| record_id | field1 | field2 | original_record_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | r0_sub_record1_field1 | r0_sub_record1_field2 | 0 |
| 1 | r0_sub_record2_field1 | r0_sub_record2_field2 | 0 |
| 2 | r1_sub_record1_field1 | r1_sub_record1_field2 | 1 |
| 3 | r2_sub_record1_field1 | r2_sub_record1_field2 | 2 |
| 4 | r2_sub_record2_field1 | r2_sub_record2_field2 | 2 |
| 5 | r2_sub_record3_field1 | r2_sub_record3_field2 | 2 |

It is quite straight-forward how to extract the data I need using a loop, but I suspect it is not the most efficient and also not the nicest way.
As I understand it, I cannot use apply or map here, because I am building another dataframe with the extracted data.

Is there a good Python-esque and  Panda-style way to solve the problem?

I am using Python 3.7 and Pandas 1.2.1.

Comment: Record 0 has already the prefix r0? Typo or not?

Comment: You're correct, that was a type. Prefixes are not relevant here, I used those as an aid to show how the first dataset should map into the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you expect?

```
out = df['text_field'].str.strip('#').str.split('#').explode() \
                      .str.split('@').apply(pd.Series)

prefix = 'r' + out.index.map(str) + '_'

out.apply(lambda v: prefix + v).reset_index() \
   .rename(columns={0: 'field1', 1: 'field2', 'index': 'original_record_id'})
```

```
>>> out
   original_record_id                 field1                 field2
0                   0  r0_sub_record1_field1  r0_sub_record1_field2
1                   0  r0_sub_record2_field1  r0_sub_record2_field2
2                   1  r1_sub_record1_field1  r1_sub_record1_field2
3                   2  r2_sub_record1_field1  r2_sub_record1_field2
4                   2  r2_sub_record2_field1  r2_sub_record2_field2
5                   2  r2_sub_record3_field1  r2_sub_record3_field2
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to `explode` based on `#` then `split` the `@` text.

```
df1 = df.assign(t=df['text_field'].str.split('#')
                 ).drop('text_field',1).explode('t').reset_index(drop=True)

df2 = df1.join(df1['t'].str.split('@',expand=True)).drop('t',1)
```

---

```
print(df2.dropna())

   record_id                      0                      1
0          0  r0_sub_record1_field1  r0_sub_record1_field2
1          0  r0_sub_record2_field1  r0_sub_record2_field2
3          1     sub_record1_field1     sub_record1_field2
5          2     sub_record1_field1     sub_record1_field2
6          2     sub_record2_field1     sub_record2_field2
7          2     sub_record3_field1     sub_record3_field2
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will investigate the explode option. The actual dataframe and the sub-field structure is a bit more complex, but I think I will be able to apply your idea!

Comment: @Raits no problem, you can also use `add_suffix` or `add_prefix` to add a common column name `df1['t'].str.split('@',expand=True).add_prefix('field_')` although it starts at zero =)